# File object and different NetBeans packages

Tags: java, file, netbeans, file-io

I like to keep my application data and and code in different Source Packages in NB (don't mistake with java packages).

So I did this time. Unfortunately it can't get files via File object from one package to another. Here's my package structure

```
Source Packages
    |-[J]basicstuff
    |-[J]net.abc.utils
  assets
    |-[F]Images
    |-[F]Layouts
```

Legend:

- No indication - source packages added in NB's project properties
- [J] Standard java package
- [F] - folder for data made with file manager

The thing is, I have my custom layout loader as I use my own GUI system. Layouts are JSON text files placed in assets/Layouts. Unfortunately my layoutmanager (which is another class in net.abc.utils) can't load them. Whatever I do, I can't load those.

I've tried

```
File layout = new File("assets/Layouts/layout.txt");
```

then

```
File layout = new File("../../../assets/Layouts/layout.txt");
```

Then I remembered it is four directories above, including src dir.

```
File layout = new File("../../../../assets/Layouts/layout.txt");
```

But it didn't work either.

Even tried

```
File layout = new File("../../../../Layouts/layout.txt");
```

and

```
File layout = new File("../../../Layouts/layout.txt");
```

But those of course also didn't work. Can you help me?

Comment: You should go back to your previous questions and accept the best answers, so that people will answer you more willingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependent on the *environment* in which your application is (*Standalone*, *ApplicationServer*), you will need to use the **appropriate** `ClassLoader`.

Try something like this:

```
private static InputStream getResourceAsStream(String resource) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String stripped = resource.startsWith("/") ? resource.substring(1) : resource;
    InputStream stream = null;
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    if (classLoader != null) {
        stream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(stripped);
    }
    if (stream == null) {
        stream = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(resource);
    }
    if (stream == null) {
        stream = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(stripped);
    }
    if (stream == null) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + resource);
    }
    return stream;
}
```

For use:

```
MyClass.getResourceAsStream("Layouts/layout.txt");
```

Comment: Well, my app is stand alone. Also main class is in basicstuff package, while layoutmanager class is inside net.abc.utils

Comment: Also resources are loaded in net.abc.utils.layoutmanager.java and passed to main function by layoutmanager's instance. And what MyClass stands for?